# Non recursive .inputrc macros

Tags: bash, keyboard-shortcuts, inputrc

I was looking to bind `"` to automatically insert a pair and put the cursor in the middle. Theoretically, like this:

```
"\"": "\"\"\C-b"
```

But this would act recursively causing this error message to pop up upon trying:

```
readline: maximum macro execution nesting level exceeded
```

So I wonder if there is a way to limit the macro so it will be non-recursive like vim's `?noremap`.

I didn't find anything in the GNU documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you haven't change the default binding for <kbd>C-v</kbd> as `quoted-insert`, you can prefix each `"` with that input quoting character:

```
"\"": "\C-v\"\C-v\"\C-b"
```

Comment: Or `"\"": '\C-v"\C-v"\eha'` if you prefer to use vi mode